# How can i do xml parse in between two consecutive tags

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I have Xml like below

```
< title>titles< title >

< description>descs< description>

< image><url>images< url>
```

And I parse them as this way

```
foreach (XmlNode item in nodes)
{
    XmlNode innode = item.SelectSingleNode("title");
    string title = innode != null ? innode.InnerText : "";
    innode = item.SelectSingleNode("description");
    string description = innode != null ? innode.InnerText : "";
    innode = item.SelectSingleNode("image");
    string imageUrl = innode != null ? innode.InnerText : "";
}
```

The first two parts are working correctly but I cant parse `< image>< url>` parts, it doesnt works with this way. How can I parse this part?

Comment: It doesn't looks like [xml](https://www.w3schools.com/xmL/xml_whatis.asp). I doubt you can use `XmlNode` for this.

Comment: I didnt write all parts. There are a lot of tags in nested nodes so when i write the post, i skip them cuz there is no problem in that places. My XmlNode is working,there is no problem

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add exact input.

Comment: Please provide a properly formatted XML input